# Split string with regex, keep delimiter at start of line

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to break a string:

- break on one of these three characters: **_ $ ***
- keep the delimiter at the beginning of the line

Examples:

```
Hello,_have a beer_or a sandwich.$Bye  =>  Hello,
                                           _have a beer
                                           _or a sandwich.
                                           *Bye

$Hello,_have a beer,$or a sandwich.*Bye  => $Hello,
                                           _have a beer,
                                           $or a sandwich.
                                           *Bye
```

I came up with this regex:

```
/_.*?(?=[_\*\$])|\*.*?(?=[_\*\$])|\$.*?(?=[_\*\$])/g
```

The problem is:

1. It doesn't capture the first part of the string when that part doesn't
   start with `* _ $`. (In the first example `Hello` is not included.)
2. It does not capture the last part of the string, because the next
   character is not `* _ $`. (in both examples `*Bye` is not included)

I've tried adding `^.*?(?=[_\*\$])` for the first part, but then parts starting with `* _ $` don't get selected.

[A fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/tLnjtH/3/)

Comment: See also "[Splitting a string into words and keeping delimiter](//stackoverflow.com/q/26184434/90527)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a positive lookeahead with the wanted chracters for splitting.

```js
var string = '$Hello,_have a beer,$or a sandwich.*Bye_ ',
    splitted = string.split(/(?=[$_*])/);
    
console.log(splitted);
```

Comment: So simple. Thank you.